# Can't connect to Azure SQL with error 18456

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-authentication

I'm trying to grant access to my Azure SQL database (on an elastic pool) to an external developer using SQL Authentication.

In the database (not master) I ran the following commands:

`create user [UserName] with password='Password', default_schema=[dbo]`

`alter role db_owner add member [UserName]`

He can't access the database, he gets the error:

`Login failed for user 'UserName'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider) Error Number: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 1 Line Number: 65536`

Both our IPs have been whitelisted, but only I can login to the database with those credentials. Any idea where things are going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i turned out that the developer hadn't specified the database in the client tool he was using (Visual Studio I think)... so sort of a fat finger error!

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of reasons their attempt to log in could fail, chief among them being they are just not typing the username or password correctly

Check [the `sys.event_log` DMV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-event-log-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current) for a more detailed reason for the login failure.  You should be able to filter to `connection_failed` events:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.event_log
WHERE event_type = 'connection_failed'
ORDER BY start_time DESC;
```

This will let you know if they are having firewall issues (`blocked_by_firewall`), timeouts (`client_close`), typos (`invalid_login_name`), etc.